# table oversized in sharelatex

Tags: tables

I'm using sharelatex for a document. I made a table that goes over the margins (see picture). I am using the follwing code

```
 \documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}

\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{table*}[htb]
\vspace*{2em}

%\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}

\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Tail Dependence.}
\label{Tails}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{13}{c}}
\toprule
\footnotesize

%\multicolumn{13}{l} 
{\textbf{Currency}} & {\textbf{AUD}} & {\textbf{HKD}}& {\textbf{INR}}& 
{\textbf{IDR}}&{\textbf{JPY}} & {\textbf{MYR}}& {\textbf{NZD}} & 
{\textbf{SGD}}& {\textbf{KRW}} & {\textbf{THB}}&{\textbf{TWD}}& 
{\textbf{PHP}} \\ \midrule
AUD&  &2.7001e-10 &0.00 &0.00 &2.1524e-03 &0.00 &5.1412e-06  &1.0069e-02 
&4.7669e-06 &0.00 &2.6925e-04   &1.3513e-02\\
HKD& 0.00 & &0.00 &3.6713e-06 &9.3193e-05 &0.00 &0.00  &0.00 &1.7274e-02 
&6.6250e-04 &1.5565e-03  &7.2932e-02\\
INR& 0.00 &0.00 & &9.1845e-06 &0.00 &1.2662e-04 &0.00 &0.00 &6.3873e-06 
&3.7516e-05 &0.00    &6.3991e-04\\
IDR& 0.00 &3.6713e-06 &9.1845e-06 & &0.00 &3.5354e-06 &3.6524e-06  &4.9311e- 
05 &0.00 &1.3955e-03 &0.00     &0.00\\
JPY& 2.1524e-03 &9.3193e-05 &4.1912e-02 &0.00 & &0.00 &8.0801e-06 &0.00 
&1.9672e-03 &0.00 &0.00     &1.7653e-05\\
MYR& 0.00 &0.00 &1.2662e-04 &3.5354e-06 &0.00 & &0.00 &0.00 &0.00 &2.5741e- 
05 &6.9101e-08   &  0.00\\
NZD& 5.1412e-06 &0.00 &0.00 &3.6524e-06 &8.0801e-06 &0.00 &  &1.1162e-02 
&1.3511e-05 &0.00 &3.8746e-02   &4.2451e-05\\
SGD& 1.0069e-02 &1.1570e-02 &0.00 &4.9311e-05 &0.00 &0.00 &0.00  & &5.5968e- 
06 &7.0886e-04 &1.1599e-04  &6.0730e-07\\
KRW& 4.7669e-06 &0.00 &6.3873e-06 &2.9146e-14 &1.9672e-03 &0.00 &1.3511e-05 
&5.5968e-06 & &0.0075 &0.0003    &0.0015\\
THB& 0.00 &6.6250e-04 &3.7516e-05 &1.3955e-03 &0.00 &2.5741e-05 &1.8844e-02 
&7.0886e-04 &0.0075 & &0.0011    &0.0321\tnote{***}\\
TWD& 2.6925e-04 &1.5565e-03 &0.00 &0.00 &0.00 &0.00 &5.3396e-07 &1.1599e-04 
&0.0003 &0.0011 &     &5.9227e-05\\
PHP& 1.3513e-02 &3.3342e-14 &6.3991e-04 &0.00 &1.7653e-05 &7.7687e-02 
&4.2451e-05 &7.5178e-02 &0.0015 &0.0321\tnote{***} &0.0507\tnote{**}     &\\
%\bottomrule
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\end{tabular*}
\smallskip
\begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
{\small

\tabfnt{***} If $\lambda_{L}$ or $\lambda_{U} \geq \mathit{Pr}[1\%]$,
\tabfnt{**} If $\lambda_{L}$ or $\lambda_{U} \geq \mathit{Pr}[5\%]$.}


%\item[***] If $\lambda_{L}$ or $\lambda_{U} \geq \mathit{Pr}[1\%]$,
%\item[**]  If $\lambda_{L}$ or $\lambda_{U} \geq \mathit{Pr}[5\%]$.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table*}
```

[image]

Comment: Please tell us which document class you use, how wide the textblock is, and what the main document font size is.

Comment: @Mico \documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}

\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: done it @samcarter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To improve the general readability and intelligibility of the table, I would like to recommend that you (a) round all exponential-type numbers to 2 digits after the decimal marker, (b) remove the redundant `0` in all expressions of the form `e-03`, etc and (c) replace all occurrences of `0.00` with just `0`.  With these adjustments in place, it's not even necessary to switch to a small font size -- again improving the intelligibility of the material. Also, unless you really like code clutter, leave off the outer curly braces around all 12 `\textbf` statements.

[image]

```
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6} 
\usepackage{rotating} 
%\usepackage{graphicx} % is loaded automatically by 'rotating' package
%\usepackage{adjustbox}
%\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{array} % <-- new
\usepackage{threeparttable} 
%\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath} 
\usepackage[american]{babel}
%\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[htb]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}

\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Tail Dependence.}
\label{Tails}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} >{\bfseries}l *{12}{l}}
\toprule
%{\textbf{Currency}} 
& \textbf{AUD} & \textbf{HKD}& \textbf{INR} & \textbf{IDR}
& \textbf{JPY} & \textbf{MYR}& \textbf{NZD} & \textbf{SGD}
& \textbf{KRW} & \textbf{THB}& \textbf{TWD} & \textbf{PHP} \\ 
\midrule
AUD&  & 2.70e-10 &0&0&2.15e-3 &0&5.14e-6  &1.01e-2 &4.77e-6 &0&2.69e-4 &1.35e-2\\
HKD& 0& &0&3.67e-6 &9.32e-5 &0&0 &0&1.73e-2 &6.63e-4 &1.56e-3  &7.29e-2\\
INR& 0&0& &9.18e-6 &0&1.27e-4 &0&0&6.39e-6 &3.75e-5 &0   &6.40e-4\\
IDR& 0&3.67e-6 &9.18e-6 & &0&3.54e-6 &3.65e-6  &4.93e-5 &0&1.40e-3 &0&0.00\\
\addlinespace % optional
JPY& 2.15e-3 &9.32e-5 &4.19e-2 &0& &0&8.08e-6 &0&1.97e-3 &0&0&1.77e-5\\
MYR& 0&0&1.27e-4 &3.54e-6 &0& &0&0&0&2.57e-5 &6.91e-8   &  0.00\\
NZD& 5.14e-6 &0&0&3.65e-6 &8.08e-6 &0&  &1.12e-2 &1.35e-5 &0&3.88e-2 &4.25e-5\\
SGD& 1.01e-2 &1.16e-2 &0&4.93e-5 &0&0&0 & &5.60e-6 &7.09e-4 &1.16e-4  &6.07e-7\\
\addlinespace % optional
KRW& 4.77e-6 &0&6.39e-6 &2.91e-14 &1.97e-3 &0&1.35e-5 &5.60e-6 & &0.0075 &0.0003 &0.0015\\
THB& 0&6.63e-4 &3.75e-5 &1.40e-3 &0&2.57e-5 &1.88e-2 &7.09e-4 &0.0075 & &0.0011 &0.0321\tnote{***} \\
TWD& 2.69e-4 &1.56e-3 &0&0&0&0&5.34e-7 &1.16e-4 &0.0003 &0.0011 & &5.92e-5\\
PHP& 1.35e-2 &3.33e-14 &6.40e-4 &0&1.77e-5 &7.77e-2 &4.25e-5 &7.52e-2 &0.0015 &0.0321\tnote{***} &0.0507\tnote{**} &\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\medskip
\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
\tabfnt{***} if $\lambda_{L}$ or $\lambda_{U} \geq \Pr[1\%]$;
\tabfnt{**}  if $\lambda_{L}$ or $\lambda_{U} \geq \Pr[5\%]$. 
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility: split the table in two

```
 \documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}

\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}


\begin{table*}[htb]
\vspace*{2em}

%\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}

\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Tail Dependence.}
\label{Tails}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{9}{c}}
\toprule
\footnotesize
{\textbf{Currency}} & {\textbf{AUD}} & {\textbf{HKD}}& {\textbf{INR}}& 
{\textbf{IDR}}&{\textbf{JPY}} & {\textbf{MYR}}& {\textbf{NZD}} & 
{\textbf{SGD}}\\ \midrule
AUD&  &2.7001e-10 &0.00 &0.00 &2.1524e-03 &0.00 &5.1412e-06  &1.0069e-02 \\
HKD& 0.00 & &0.00 &3.6713e-06 &9.3193e-05 &0.00 &0.00  &0.00 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\bigskip
\begin{tabular*}{.6\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{5}{c}}
\toprule
\footnotesize
{\textbf{Currency}} & {\textbf{KRW}} & {\textbf{THB}}&{\textbf{TWD}}& 
{\textbf{PHP}} \\ \midrule
AUD& 4.7669e-06 &0.00 &2.6925e-04   &1.3513e-02\\
HKD& 1.7274e-02 &6.6250e-04 &1.5565e-03  &7.2932e-02\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}




\smallskip
\begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
{\small

\tabfnt{***} If $\lambda_{L}$ or $\lambda_{U} \geq \mathit{Pr}[1\%]$,
\tabfnt{**} If $\lambda_{L}$ or $\lambda_{U} \geq \mathit{Pr}[5\%]$.}


%\item[***] If $\lambda_{L}$ or $\lambda_{U} \geq \mathit{Pr}[1\%]$,
%\item[**]  If $\lambda_{L}$ or $\lambda_{U} \geq \mathit{Pr}[5\%]$.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]